# How to use this linker script program?

Tags: c, eclipse, linker, ld, linker-scripts

If I write a code in my program.c as a global declaration :

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION (measurements, ".myvarloc");
uint8 measurements[30];
```

i write the below code and save it as a.ld:

```
MEMORY
{
        MYMEMORY(rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x0041c620 ,  LENGTH = 30
}

.myvars (NOLOAD) :
{
  *(. myvarloc)

} > MYMEMORY
```

Later I will specify the path of the a.ld in linker section. 
If i do like above, the address of the memory will be fixed ??
Is it the right way to do ??
Could anyone tell me how to do the linker setting in Eclipse OR visual studio C++ ide ??

I am creating a fixed memory address and later using this address for storing in a file on the master. Is there any other alternative solution ??

Comment: _'Is it the right way to do ??'_ What are your actual results/problems?

Comment: just did like that and don't know how to add .ld in the ide ?? Is that the right procedure to do ??

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question correctly, you're using Eclipse CDT to manage that VS-2008 project, and selected MSVC toolchain?

I don't have that much experience with setting properties for this kind of toolchain, but I'm pretty sure there should be some option for the MSVC linker that allows to specify a linker script and that can be set using the `C/C++ Build.>Settings->Linker->General` project properties.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. I also know that but don't know where exactly !!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, VC++ does not support/understand linker scripts. However, you can use the `section` pragma (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/section?view=msvc-170) to manually place data into specific sections.